# Multiple message types per Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

Suppose I have a Kafka topic named `account` with several message types (each one with a different Avro schema), like `account.created`, `account.deleted` and so on.
I would like to understand if it is feasible (and it makes sense) to publish/receive different types on the same topics with Spring Cloud Stream. In particular, it would be very useful to have several `@StreamListener`, each one dedicated to a particular type. According to [this blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/) this is really useful when having the need to order messages because they are related to the same entity. What is an example of the configuration in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about content-based routing which allows messages to be delivered to a specific `StreamListener` for cases where there are multiple.
You do so by using `condition` attribute. Please refer to [this section](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing) for more details and let us know if it is still unclear or not what you're looking for.

Comment: That's what I needed I think. Do you know if this can also work with `useNativeDecoding: true`?

Comment: I don't see why not